# "Qui va là ?" et "Qui est là ?"

Tags: expressions, questions, militaire

Je connais l'emploi et l'origine militaire de l'expression *Qui va là ?*. Je me demande si l'on peut l'employer couramment comme une variante (humoristique peut-être) de *Qui est là ?*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oui bien sûr ça peut être employé à la place de « qui est là ? », mais je pense que c'est plus proche de « qui passe par là ? ». Je ne le dirais pas si quelqu'un frappe à ma porte mais plutôt si j'entends un bruit incongru et que je ne vois pas qui en est la cause.

Mais je pense que ça fait désuet,  peut-être parce que ça me rappelle toujours la réplique du soldat dans *Le malade imaginaire* !

C'est toujours employé pour faire un effet stylistique, mais pas forcément de l'humour. Ça peut faire partie d'un langage volontairement érudit. Voici un extrait d'un essai (un essai littéraire : *Céphalophores* de [Sylvie Germain](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvie_Germain)).

> « Qui va là ? »
>   Et si telle était la question initiale qui abruptement se pose, – s’impose, à tout lecteur ouvrant un livre et s’apprêtant à s’aventurer dans les méandres d’un texte ? Qui donc est dans ces pages, qui se tient en amont de ce livre, qui va au fil des lignes, qui parle dans ces phrases ?
>   Qui va là ? L’auteur et ses personnages se trouvent interpellés. Mais l’interpellation a commencé bien avant déjà : dès que l’auteur a convoqué ses personnages, ou plutôt, dès que les personnages, encore informes, innomés, incertains, s’en sont venus solliciter l’auteur, quérir son attention et provoquer en lui désir, curiosité, tourment. Car d’où provient au juste l’initiative : de l’auteur, ou des figures qu’il met en forme, en situation, en scène ?

C'est un texte où chaque mot est pesé et volontairement employé pour faire un effet. Mais ça n'a rien d'humoristique ici. Et ici c'est  « qui passe par là » et pas « qui est là ».